# about function series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

Good evening, everyone,

Could anyone please tell me how to check if the series $\sum_{k\geq 2}\dfrac{1}{k^4+x}$ is greater than $C\sum_{k\geq 2}\dfrac{1}{k^2+x}$ where $C$ is independent of the positive variable $x$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take $x$ of the form $t^4$, where $t\gt 0$. Since $$\sum_{k\geqslant 2}\frac 1{k^2+t^4}\geqslant\sum_{k\geqslant 2}\frac 1{(k+t^2)^2}=\sum_{j\geqslant t^2}\frac 1{j^2}\sim \frac 1{t^2}$$
and 
$$\sum_{k\geqslant 2}\frac 1{k^4+t^4}\leqslant 4\sum_{k\geqslant t}\frac 1{k^4}\sim \frac 4{t^3},$$
the constant $C$ cannot exist.